# desktop database application sync with server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, synchronization

I have a windows form database application which run on several computers.

I want to keep the application database continuously sync with the server database, in order for my users to use the same data.

**Can someone tell me how to sync continuously the application database with the server database?**

the application is done in visual basic, and both databases local and server are done in MSSQL.

I am looking for a safe and simple method because I am a beginner developer.

Comment: [read about replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

Comment: You'll need to set up merge replication.  If you can rework the program to always use the server database that will save you a lot of time and major headaches with database replication.  I know that might not be possible, but if it is that is the best way to go.

Comment: I manage to create a synchronization class, using Microsoft sync Framework which is working ok. Because I am a beginner and have no experience, I want to ask you what possible issues I must expect by using this method of synchronization?